# how to dynamically load html into div in using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two files Mypage.Html , PageLogic.js

HTML page contains multi-step form

In first step Based on user selection for his interest(drop-down/radio buttons)
step_2 Div is visible(step 2 form is different for each interest topics)

Step_2 structure is like

```
<div id="step_2">
  <div id="interestTopic_1">
      Long html with different form fields......
  </div>
  <div id="interestTopic_2">
      Long html with different form fields......
  </div>
  <div id="interestTopic_3">
      Long html with different form fields......
  </div>
  <div id="interestTopic_4">
      Long html with different form fields......
  </div>
  <div id="interestTopic_5">
      Long html with different form fields......
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to add "interestTopic" div to step_2 div dynamically based on values selection from step_1 , Each interestTopic may contains different text fields/input controls.How can i add this div dynamically and also want to use input controls inside div in same js from which i added that div..
Is This Possible without server call? I tried simple hide/show but when you are loading a page and then filling first form long html cause page to freeze for 1-2 seconds

Comment: Still facing any problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. For your reference here I have added "interestTopic" `div` to "step_2" `div` as a child dynamically through button click with input box.

```js
var i=6;
$("#add").click(function () {
                $("#step_2").children().last().after('<div id="interestTopic_'+i+'"><input type="text" value="Test"/></div>');
i++;
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="step_2">
        <div id="interestTopic_1">
            Long html with different form fields......
        </div>
        <div id="interestTopic_2">
            Long html with different form fields......
        </div>
        <div id="interestTopic_3">
            Long html with different form fields......
        </div>
        <div id="interestTopic_4">
            Long html with different form fields......
        </div>
        <div id="interestTopic_5">
            Long html with different form fields......
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="add">Add New Div</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can update the innerHTML of step_2 div using .innerHTML like this:

```
document.getElementById("step_2").innerHTML ="<your new div based on the user selection from step 1>";
```

This approach will give you only one div inside your step_2 div. Alternatively, you may place all the divs initially in the DOM with display:none and then show the desired div per user inputs.

Comment: Why not use `$('#step_2').html("<whatever>");` ?

Comment: `innerHTML` isn't a valid property for jq object